Using circular saw and other power tools with low Roman workbench?
I want to build a workbench, and I’ve seen videos of low benches being built and used. I like the idea of sitting down to work. But I also like using my power tools—mainly my circular saw and router.
What’s it like to use power tools with low benches?

This is kind of opinion driven. If you imagine yourself swinging a circular saw on what you’d call typical, how do you think it feels? (Personally, my arms are too short to imagine cutting anything useful while sitting. Ymmv.)


What’s it like to use power tools with low benches?

What's it like to do any operation on low benches?
The experience of doing A, B, C and D, on to M or N, on such a bench is entirely down to the user. But the simple fact that the benches in power-tool workshops aren't typically low even by normal workbench standards does tell us something immediately1.
Ponder the following for the circular saw only to start with:

individual stature;
the exact height of the finished workbench and how that relates to 1;
the circular saw in question — right-cutting v left-cutting — its size, Wattage/hp, the location of the power button;
the dominant hand and how that relates to 3;
the cuts envisaged and how they relate to 3 and 4;
the presence of a make-do attitude, or dogged persistence;

and one can see it's driven by numerous factors. But it may fundamentally come down mostly to individual user experience and preferences.
Now I think you should delve deeper. Take your circular saw, unplugged or with the battery removed, and mime the various operations you would want to do. Don't be shy, nobody is watching (unless you want them too LOL), go full-on Marcel Marceau here when it comes to what could happen if there's an accident, in terms of where the saw will want to go and how that motion relates to various body parts you want to keep attached or unmangled.
Next do the same for the router. Go through all the envisaged operations; think about safe/effective workholding but especially if you plan to be seated during any of them think where the router bit might be going if there's an accident; factor in both a bit ejection2 and a sudden self-feed.

1 However, in workshops that have benches built pretty much exclusively for power-tool use (taller than typical hand-tool benches) it isn't uncommon for one of the major uses of the circ. saw — initial breakdown cuts of sheet goods — to be done low down, in fact in many cases on the floor, e.g. on thick insulation foam. So there's definitely something to working lower for some operations.
2 Partial or complete — bit breaks, or comes loose from the collet.

I can offer my experience as someone who has worked on a low Roman bench for the last 9 months or so.
The two power tools I’ve used on it are a drill (convenient height for drilling chairs with very long drill bits) and a small 8” bandsaw.
However, I would never even think of using a circular saw or a router on it. (I have a secondary bench made of a Bora Centipede and a sheet of plywood that’s perfect for this purpose.)
When straddling the low bench, you are always in the way of the cut line. So if the tool kicks back, it’s going right into your body. You can kneel beside the bench, but that seems awkward (also, my floors are dirty), and why kneel or crouch when there are other options?
The main benefit of the low bench is that it is robust and stable enough for hand tool use while being relatively easy to make. This benefit is negated with power tools, because power tools do not require such a stable platform. My Centipede is plenty stable, for example. You can also use sawhorses etc.
